# How to stay on a single thread while debugging an application in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-2017

While debugging an ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2017, I am facing an issue with multiple threads. The code flow stepping into other threads too.

I have tried using Debug -> Windows -> Threads to freeze the unwanted threads at the first break point. But it's not working as expected. Also, tried to set a thread condition for breakpoints to filter out the other threads.

I would like to know how to stop debugging into multiple threads and stay on the current for all the break points.

**Note:** I have Resharper installed in my Visual Studio. I want to know whether I can handle this using Resharper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio, debug one of multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901736/visual-studio-debug-one-of-multiple-threads)

Comment: i know its not really what you asked but you can hit F5 on the other threads, You will still continue to single step on the one you are interested in