# how to debug multithreaded application for asp .net with c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application with code first entity. I want to debug a multi-threaded module.

One approach i have followed to use logger but i think this is not right way. Please suggest the best way?

Comment: Why? Exactly? Tried what? What exactly you want?

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901736/visual-studio-debug-one-of-multiple-threads